# Не инициализируется FirebaseApp

Tags: android, firebase-database, firebase-android

Пытаюсь запустить чужой код. Не инициализируется FirebaseApp. Пытался добавить

```
FirebaseApp app = FirebaseApp.initializeApp(getApplicationContext());
```

возвращает null. google-services.json присутствует. В чём может быть дело?

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.app.chimaster, PID: 18115
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create application com.app.chimaster.TheApp: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process com.app.chimaster. Make sure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first.
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6737)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2000(ActivityThread.java:273)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2020)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:112)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:216)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7625)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:524)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:987)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process com.app.chimaster. Make sure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first.
        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.getInstance(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@16.0.1:219)
        at com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase.getInstance(Unknown Source:0)
        at com.app.chimaster.TheApp.onCreate(TheApp.java:27)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1162)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6717)
```

Answer (score 0):

Помогло выставление последней версии в build.gradle:Project

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
```

До этого была 4.1.0 - видимо уже не поддерживается.